Conditional Multivariate Normal Distribution
I'm wondering how to compute the mean vector and covariance matrix of a conditional multivariate normal distribution in practice. Wikipedia says that if we have $\boldsymbol X\sim\mathcal N(\boldsymbol\mu,\boldsymbol\Sigma)$ with $\boldsymbol X\in\mathbb R^n$, and we want to partition the variables as $\boldsymbol X=[\boldsymbol X_1,\boldsymbol X_2]$ with \begin{align*}\boldsymbol\mu&=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol\mu_1\\\boldsymbol\mu_2\end{bmatrix}&\boldsymbol\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol\Sigma_{11}&\boldsymbol\Sigma_{12}\\\boldsymbol\Sigma_{21}&\boldsymbol\Sigma_{22}\end{bmatrix}\end{align*}
and fix $\boldsymbol x_2=\boldsymbol a$, then the new mean and covariance of $\boldsymbol X_1$ becomes
\begin{align*}
\bar{\boldsymbol\mu} &= \boldsymbol\mu_1+\boldsymbol\Sigma_{12}\boldsymbol\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(\boldsymbol\alpha-\boldsymbol\mu_2)\\
\bar{\boldsymbol\Sigma} &= \boldsymbol\Sigma_{11}-\boldsymbol\Sigma_{12}\boldsymbol\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\boldsymbol\Sigma_{21}.
\end{align*}
$\bar{\boldsymbol\Sigma}$ is apparently the Schur complement of $\boldsymbol\Sigma_{22}$ in $\boldsymbol\Sigma$. But this seems to be only defined for block matrices. What if I want to fix an arbitrary set of indices $I\subseteq\lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace$ to values $a_i~\forall i\in I$?
I'm aware that I could probably define a permutation matrix $P$ that moves all variables with indices in $I$ to the end and compute $\bar{\boldsymbol\Sigma'}$ for $\boldsymbol\Sigma'=\boldsymbol\Sigma P$, but this seems overly complicated. Is there a more direct way? (I want to implement this in NumPy …)
Also Wikipedia says that $\boldsymbol\Sigma_{22}^{-1}$ is a generalized inverse, why is that?
Thanks in advance for your helpful comments!
